# PHP script times out with error 500 when running large amount of data

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I have a php script that sends over 7000 Soap requests, it executes until it reaches ~200 request and then the page throws error 500.

I have edited the following in php.ini:

```
max_execution_time = 18000
max_input_time = 18000
memory_limit = 1024M
```

It's still times out at same thing.
Same happens if I try to fetch same amount of data from MySQL and export them as CSV, the script times out.

What should I do?

Comment: you should be getting an error more specific to your issue, can you post that as well? If you don't have error_reporting enabled, you should enable it always for development.

Comment: I have it enabled but I don't get any error other than this.

Comment: Well I would check your logs for the fatal error. Without the exact error message it will be a guessing game to determine why it is failing. 

If you know it is the execution time, try `max_execution_time = 0`, but that is not a great solution. You should instead look at batching these requests in some way.

Comment: i tried setting it to 0 and it still times out, when I check phpinfo(); it shows that my settings are being applied.

Comment: Would you please tell me how could i check these logs? i'm using godaddy cpanel hosting.